# Unable to use api to read data in android studio, Although all permissions were given

Tags: java, android, api, okhttp

I am trying to get data from API using okhttpclient in android studio. But it is neither throwing exception nor retrieving data. The same API with okhttpclient works well in a java project in IntelliJ. I also gave android internet permission in the manifest file.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(Configuration.EASY_URL)
                        .build();
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        // Check if the request was successful (HTTP 200-299)
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Get the response body as a string
                            String responseBody = response.body().string();

                            // Do something with the response body
                            System.out.println(responseBody);
                            Log.d("Response", responseBody);
                        } else {
                            // Request was not successful
                            Log.d("Request Failed", "Code: " + response.code());
                        }

                        // Close the response to release resources
                        response.close();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

On clicking the button I am trying to get data from the API. But the process keeps on running and there is no error in logcat or console.

This is the URL I am trying to access

```
public static String EASY_URL= "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=21&difficulty=easy&type=multiple";
```

Comment: Ok. Looks like this is happening only on emulators. On a real device with debugging mode, I am able to get data.